# image rotation not working on Samsung Galaxy Nexus android

Tags: android, android-image, samsung-mobile

I've tested this code snippet on about 25 devices and it works great on all of them except a Samsung Galaxy Nexus that I'm trying to test with now.

Here is the method and I apologize for not trimming it down to find the exact spot that's throwing the exception, but eclipse's debugging is doodoo.

```
private void setupImageView() {
    imageLocation = currentPhotoPath;


    // Get the dimensions of the View
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = getDisplaySize(display);
    int targetW = size.x;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetW);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, bmOptions);
    //int rotationForImage = getRotationForImage(imageLocation);
    int rotationForImage = (whichCamera == 0 ? 90 : 270);
    if (rotationForImage != 0) {
        int targetWidth = rotationForImage == 90 || rotationForImage == 270 ? bitmap.getHeight() : bitmap.getWidth();
        int targetHeight = rotationForImage == 90 || rotationForImage == 270 ? bitmap.getWidth() : bitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, bitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(rotationForImage, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());

        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = rotatedBitmap;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        try
        {
                File f = new File(imageLocation);
                f.createNewFile();
                //write the bytes in file
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e){}
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

anyone know what Samsung does differently with the nexus that would cause this to throw an exception?  It works fine on a Galaxy S III

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious... whats the exception?

Comment: The exception is being thrown in my onActivityResult() which calls the above pasted method when the intent closes and returns to the previous activity.  I've narrowed it down further to the rotation bit by manually setting the rotation for image to 0.  In that case nothing in the if block is called.  Here's the exception: 12-10 15:08:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=904, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.myapp}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It looks like something in the if block you mention is throwing an NPE - that's the real bug here. Don't worry about the Activity/ResultInfo stuff, that is downstream and triggered by the NPE. Go line by line and look for the null reference.

Comment: it looks like any of the methods on the bitmap object are causing it to puke.  Even if I comment out everything except this line: int targetWidth = rotationForImage == 90 || rotationForImage == 270 ? bitmap.getHeight() : bitmap.getWidth(); it throws an exception.  I can't get breakpoints to work on eclipse so I apologize again for not being able to provide better info.  But I have narrowed it down to it being methods called on the bitmap object at least....this works for all other devices except this one (that I've found so far anyway).

Comment: ok it turns out my my camera intent wasn't passing the path string down to my calling activity so you were right, it was a null pointer exception.  If you wanna write that up as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks much.  any tips for debugging better with eclipse?

Comment: Just wondering - why would the NPE not have affected the 24 other devices you tested on?  What's different about the Galaxy Nexus?  (I ask because am also struggling with some bitmap/camera issues on Galaxy Nexus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something in the if block you mention is throwing an NPE - that's the real bug here. Don't worry about the Activity/ResultInfo stuff, that is downstream and triggered by the NPE. Go line by line and look for the null reference :-)

Regarding Eclipse - sadly I don't have much experience there. For Android I personally use IntelliJ and the debugging works well. Are you able to debug other Java code (even a simple Hello, World)?

Comment: the logging is pretty decent with eclipse especially Log.d() events.  I'm just accustomed to visual studio where I can toss in a break point and actually have the process stop on that breakpoint so I can see property values etc.  If IntelliJ allows for that while debugging on an actual device (not the emulator), say the word and I'll make the switch.

Comment: I can confirm that I have used IntelliJ to get breakpoint + inspection debugging on an actual device :-)